# Statistics compared to other sites

Tags: discussion

Not a question as such, but I wanted to make a record of our stats cf. other sites as of November 4th, 2011:

Total number of stackexchange sites on http://stackexchange.com/sites: 72

Travel.SE. Columns are: Criteria, rank (num), number of sites out of beta that we beat:

- Questions - 49th (787 questions), 0
- Answers - 51st (1713), 1/32
- % answers - 6th (not sure exactly how this is ordered as a bunch have 100% but we do technically have a couple of unanswered questions), 31/32
- Users: 52nd (1177), 0
- Vists/day: 55th (361/day), 0

I thought this was interesting, especially since Travel was created 58th out of 72, and we're ahead of some older sites.  So to those concerned about stats, we're doing fine, growth will come, and will include a sudden boost if and when we come out of beta.

EDIT - UPDATE (25/11/11)

Still 72 sites.

- Questions: 46th, 885 questions, 0
- Answers: 49th, 1.9k, 1
- % answers, 15th, slipped a bit on this, 30/32.
- Users: 48th, 1330, 0.
- Traffic, 53rd, 341/day, 0.

**Stats as of December 17, 2011:**

Total number of stackexchange sites on http://stackexchange.com/sites: 74

Travel.SE. Columns are: Criteria, rank (num), number of sites out of beta that we beat:

- Questions - 51st (1017 questions), 0
- Answers - 49th (2215), 1/32
- % answers - 10th equal (not sure exactly how this is ordered as a bunch have 99% but we do technically have a couple of unanswered questions), 28/32
- Users: 49th (1478), 0 (300+ since last update!)
- Vists/day: 52nd (432/day), 0
- New 200+ rep users: 25, 19th!
- Questions per day - 6.1, 35th!
- New  Meta Posts - 78, **8th (top 10!)**

[Current traffic trend](http://www.quantcast.com/travel.stackexchange.com)

[image]

Comment: I find this very hard to read. For instance what is the "0 Answers" after "Questions - 49th (787 questions)"? Can you maybe format it another way?

Comment: Wow, it _was_ formatted, not sure what on earth happened there.  Will try and remedy now.

Comment: Just today our views increased again heavily

Comment: Thanks for the update. Seems as if the visits are going back again.

Comment: I think votes per question (counting votes on the Q as well as all the As) would be an interesting stat as well.  My anecdotal assessment is that this site gives more rep per question than any other site I am on, including both several non-beta ones with huge membership numbers, and several betas. That may be another thing we can't track until we get Data Explorer access, though.

Comment: yup, not available through my methods currently :/

Comment: **Those were the days!**

Answer (score 5):

The visits per day is skyrocketing lately. It was about 270 Oct 27th, 361 Nov 3rd when you wrote this, 414 Nov 4th, 453 Nov 8th, ... whatever we're all doing we should keep doing it. I think visits/day is the one metric we can actually drive, and all the others follow from it.

Comment: True, but if it's a moving average it'll still be distorted by the Squatting question, like it was briefly with the Vodka question.  Give it a few days to see.  But yes, just pushing visits will surely equal questions, and answers.  But so will good content, as search traffic is generally the majority of traffic for sites out of beta.  More quality content, more answers and more of it will be found by Google etc.

Comment: I think people show up for the vodka/squatting questions, spot some others that interest them, and with luck stick around. I also think the closer those "out there" questions are to our regular fare, the more likely we are to retain folks who are attracted by the wild ones.

Comment: Totally agree.   The fun ones get lots of people, but we need to retain them.